# jquery ui autocomplete result are too small

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I am sure that i am missing something but don't know what. I have an jquery autocomplete field that gets data from a mysql query. I am getting the results but drop down list has a height only few pixels per result.

data i use is

```
[{"id":1,"name":"France","created_at":"2016-06-18 05:05:27","updated_at":"2016-06-18 05:05:27"},{"id":2,"name":"United Kingdom","created_at":"2016-06-18 05:05:38","updated_at":"2016-06-18 05:05:38"},{"id":3,"name":"Sweden","created_at":"2016-06-18 05:05:46","updated_at":"2016-06-18 05:05:46"},{"id":4,"name":"Norway","created_at":"2016-06-18 05:05:50","updated_at":"2016-06-18 05:05:50"},{"id":5,"name":"Hungary","created_at":"2016-06-18 05:05:56","updated_at":"2016-06-18 05:05:56"},{"id":6,"name":"Germany","created_at":"2016-06-18 05:06:01","updated_at":"2016-06-18 05:06:01"},{"id":7,"name":"Austria","created_at":"2016-06-18 05:06:09","updated_at":"2016-06-18 05:06:09"},{"id":8,"name":"Slovakia","created_at":"2016-06-18 05:06:15","updated_at":"2016-06-18 05:06:15"},{"id":9,"name":"Romania","created_at":"2016-06-18 05:06:22","updated_at":"2016-06-18 05:06:22"},{"id":10,"name":"Ukraine","created_at":"2016-06-18 05:06:28","updated_at":"2016-06-18 05:06:28"}]
```

If data is formated like this:

```
["France","United Kingdom","Sweden","Norway","Hungary","Germany","Austria","Slovakia","Romania","Ukraine"]
```

its shown as it should. Thing is i would need id field later on 
here is the code

```
<script> $(function(){
 $( "#cname" ).autocomplete({
  source: "{{url('country/complete')}}",
  minLength: 3,
  select: function(event, ui) {
    $('#cname').val(ui.item.name);
      }
   });
}); 
</script>
```

and

```
<div class="form-group">
     {!! Form::label('cname','Country')!!}
     {!! Form::text('cname', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
</div>
```

Here is the css and js

```
<!-- Styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-I6F5OKECLVtK/BL+8iSLDEHowSAfUo76ZL9+kGAgTRdiByINKJaqTPH/QVNS1VDb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```
    <style>
    body {
        font-family: 'Lato';
    }

    .fa-btn {
        margin-right: 6px;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! This sounds like a problem with styles. Do you have some CSS that you could add to your question for us to see?

Comment: i've edited my post

Comment: Hello! Do you want selected country name as well as id or drop down list height or few results problem?

Comment: Plan/ponit is to use id to sumbit form but iv've got stuck with autocomplete size - anoying thing that it works only with 1 data format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery autocomplete can work with 3 formats of data (actually more, I'll soon get into it).

This all comes from the [jQuery Autocomplete API documentation, source() option](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source).

**Option 1: Use an array.**

This is what you're doing in the first example with the array of country names. As you probably detected, this completely gets rid of the IDs so you cannot later relate the user selection to the actual country name, unless you do a reverse search but that's just inefficient.

```js
$(function() {
  /******************** FIRST EXAMPLE *************************/
  var countryNames = ["France", "United Kingdom", "Sweden", "Norway", "Hungary", "Germany", "Austria", "Slovakia", "Romania", "Ukraine"];

  $("#cname1").autocomplete({
    source: countryNames,
    minLength: 3,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      console.debug("Selected value: " + ui.item.value);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lato';
}
.fa-btn {
  margin-right: 6px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-I6F5OKECLVtK/BL+8iSLDEHowSAfUo76ZL9+kGAgTRdiByINKJaqTPH/QVNS1VDb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="cname1">Country (from array of strings)</label>
  <input type="text" id="cname1" name="cname1" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

**Option 2: Use a label-value pair array.**

jQuery autocomplete will properly understand an array of objects if you make sure that each of them has a label and a value property. These two will map, respectively, to the value shown in the screen, and to the value stored internally by the autocomplete.

Now, the trick here is that once the user selects a value, the ID will be later used as the value of the input, which you don't want because you probably still prefer the user to look at a country name, not a numerical ID.

By just testing I saw that jQuery autocomplete actually gives you back the original object which you pass to it, so you can give it id and label, it will ignore ID and show always label, but you can read it from the select event.

```js
$(function() {
  /******************** SECOND EXAMPLE *************************/
  var countries = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "France",
    "created_at": "2016-06-18 05:05:27",
    "updated_at": "2016-06-18 05:05:27"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "United Kingdom",
    "created_at": "2016-06-18 05:05:38",
    "updated_at": "2016-06-18 05:05:38"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Sweden",
    "created_at": "2016-06-18 05:05:46",
    "updated_at": "2016-06-18 05:05:46"
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Norway",
    "created_at": "2016-06-18 05:05:50",
    "updated_at": "2016-06-18 05:05:50"
  }, {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Hungary",
    "created_at": "2016-06-18 05:05:56",
    "updated_at": "2016-06-18 05:05:56"
  }, {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Germany",
    "created_at": "2016-06-18 05:06:01",
    "updated_at": "2016-06-18 05:06:01"
  }, {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Austria",
    "created_at": "2016-06-18 05:06:09",
    "updated_at": "2016-06-18 05:06:09"
  }, {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Slovakia",
    "created_at": "2016-06-18 05:06:15",
    "updated_at": "2016-06-18 05:06:15"
  }, {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Romania",
    "created_at": "2016-06-18 05:06:22",
    "updated_at": "2016-06-18 05:06:22"
  }, {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Ukraine",
    "created_at": "2016-06-18 05:06:28",
    "updated_at": "2016-06-18 05:06:28"
  }];

  var formattedCountries = countries.map(function(c) {
    return {
      label: c.name,
      id: c.id
    }
  });

  $("#cname2").autocomplete({
    source: formattedCountries,
    minLength: 3,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      console.debug("Selected value: " + ui.item.id);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lato';
}
.fa-btn {
  margin-right: 6px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-I6F5OKECLVtK/BL+8iSLDEHowSAfUo76ZL9+kGAgTRdiByINKJaqTPH/QVNS1VDb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="cname2">Country (from array of objects)</label>
  <input type="text" id="cname2" name="cname2" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

**Option 3: URL String.**

Simple: an URL string where jQuery autocomplete will query for the results. The results need to be in one of the formats mentioned above.

**Option 4: Use your own objects, tell the widget how to render them:**

Sorry, I'll be lazy here.

You can check the [Autocomplete custom data example](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data). It makes use of the `_renderItem` function, so you can tell exactly jQuery how you want to render HTML and what properties of the object you want to use.

**So, why did you see that it had only a few items in height?**

(Disclaimer: Speculation zone here.)

[image: Autocomplete empty]

This happens if you have property names in the source that jQuery autocomplete does not wait. For example, "name" and "id". It will actually show an autocomplete value, but that will be empty, and that will be shown as a very-small portion of the screen.

My speculation is that this is what you saw.

I hope this helped!

**Also:**

- [Both snippets in one JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Alpha/pLy1vu1d/)

Comment: the problem was i had no link between id and value and name and label , so what it did was made (country/complete result page) a json with only label and value data. Alpha thanks for help

Comment: @aleksandar I'm glad I was able to help!